# Create deadlock scenario without foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, deadlock

I need to test my C# code in a SQL Server deadlock scenario.  Is there a way to create a deadlock "*on demand*"?

I have tried this:

```
Begin Transaction 
Select * from TABLEA with (tablockx, holdlock)
Where 0 = 1
WaitFor Delay '00:02:00'
--Rollback Transaction
```

But the second connection just waits and until after the `Delay`, and then does its job.

In the second session I do

```
Update TABLEA 
Set LastUpdatedBy = 'IT_TESTING'
Where OrderRefProviderId = 397685
WaitFor Delay '00:00:30'
```

Comment: [Brent has an easy script](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/05/how-to-create-deadlocks-and-troubleshoot-them/) to illustrate what you are trying to do.[Here's another on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825825/6167855)

Comment: @scsimon damn it missed the last step.  If you wanna put the links in an answer with a little blurb, I will credit you for your time.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to help!